# Combining sidewaystable, adjustbox and threeparttablex

Tags: rotating, adjustbox, tablenotes, threeparttablex, sidewaystable

I need to have a table which 1) is sideways 2) is rescaled to fit the page 3) has `tablenotes`. I'm trying to combine `sidewaystable`, `adjustbox` and `threeparttablex` to do so, but I encounter three problems:

1. I don't know where/how to include the table caption. I tried several positions within the environments but I keep getting compilation errors.
2. The width of the `tablenotes` is not correct, not even after including `\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth}`
3. Labels "b" and "c" overlap in the third cell of the first row.

This is what my current MWE attempt looks like (the actual table is much larger, hence the sidewaystable/adjustbox combination):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\linewidth}
\begin{TableNotes}
\small
\item [a] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [b] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [c] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
%\caption{My table caption.} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multirow{2}{*}{Specification\tnote{a}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Covariance structure\tnote{a}\tnote{b}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of fixed effects\tnote{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of variance components\tnote{c}} \\ \cline{4-7} 
&                                &                                  & ES approach          & RD approach          & ES approach             & RD approach             \\ \hline
$1$                      &     Model 1                           & Covariance 1                                      & $1$                    & $2$                    & $2$                       & $7$                       \\
$2$                      &     Model 2                           & Covariance 2                                      & $2$                    & $4$                    & $6$                       & $21$                      \\
$3 $                     &     Model 3                           & Covariance 3                                      & $3$                    & $6$                    & $12$                      & $43$                      \\ \hline
\insertTableNotes
\end{tabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is best to never scale tables even in cases where it doesn't give an error, it produces inconsistent font sizes and poor output.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 4):

Only scale tables as a last resort (and even then don't do it) also as you are using threeepartx rather than threepart I think you want longtable rather than tabular

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\small
\item [a] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [b] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [c] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{lllllll}
%\caption{My table caption.}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multirow{2}{*}{Specification\tnote{a}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Covariance structure\tnote{a}\tnote{b}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of fixed effects\tnote{c}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of variance components\tnote{c}} \\ \cline{4-7} 
&                                &                                  & ES approach          & RD approach          & ES approach             & RD approach             \\ \hline
$1$                      &     Model 1                           & Covariance 1                                      & $1$                    & $2$                    & $2$                       & $7$                       \\
$2$                      &     Model 2                           & Covariance 2                                      & $2$                    & $4$                    & $6$                       & $21$                      \\
$3 $                     &     Model 3                           & Covariance 3                                      & $3$                    & $6$                    & $12$                      & $43$                      \\ \hline
\insertTableNotes
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the table -- including table footnotes -- has to fit on a single page, I wouldn't use the machinery of the `longtable` and `ThreePartTable` environments. Moreover, I wouldn't use the `adjustbox` machinery either, as it will almost certainly cause wildly inconsistent font sizes across parts of the documents.

I can't see how you can go wrong employing `sidewaystable`, `threeparttable`, `tabularx`, and `tablenotes` environments. In particular, using a `tabularx` environment and allowing line breaks in cells should remove any need to resort to the `adjustbox` sledgehammer. For well-spaced horizontal lines or "rules", do consider loading the `booktabs` package and employing its `\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` macros. And, instead of `\tnote{a}\tnote{b}`, do write `\tnote{a,b}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
%\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % select the appropriate page parameters
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\minitab[1]{\smash{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{My table caption.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Model & 
Specification\tnote{a} & 
\minitab{Covariance\\structure\tnote{a,b}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{E}{Number of fixed effects\tnote{c}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{E@{}}{Number of variance components\tnote{c}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& & & ES approach & RD approach & ES approach & RD approach \\ 
\midrule
$1$ & Model 1 & Covariance 1 & $1$ & $2$ & $2$ &  $7$ \\
$2$ & Model 2 & Covariance 2 & $2$ & $4$ & $6$ & $21$ \\
$3$ & Model 3 & Covariance 3 & $3$ & $6$ & $12$& $43$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip % or "\smallskip"
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item [a] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note 
          nnote note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [b] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note 
          note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [c] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note 
          note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`threeparttablex` is for use with `longtable` not ordinary `tabular`.  Use `threeparttable` commands for a `tabular`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{.9\linewidth}
\caption{My table caption.}
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{l}}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}{*}{Model}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{Specification\tnote{a}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{Covariance structure\tnote{a,b}\ }
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of fixed effects\tnote{c}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Number of variance components\tnote{c}} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){4-7}
  & & & ES approach & RD approach & ES approach & RD approach \\
  \midrule
  $1$ & Model 1 & Covariance 1 & $1$ & $2$ & $2$ & $7$ \\
  $2$ & Model 2 & Covariance 2 & $2$ & $4$ & $6$ & $21$ \\
  $3$ & Model 3 & Covariance 3 & $3$ & $6$ & $12$ & $43$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item [a] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [b] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\item [c] Note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Note loading `threeparttablex` will work equally well, it loads `threeparttable`, you just have to use the commands from `threeparttable`.

I used `\tnote{a,b}` for the two adjacent notes.  I added a manual space `\` afterwards to give a bit more room.

I have used the `booktabs` package for nicer rules including the `\cmidrule`  which can be shortened slightly on either side